# Is there any frontend tool / widget for eject application (opening / closing disc tray)?

Tags: dvd, cinnamon, system-tray

The [eject](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/eject.1.html) command allows to eject / open CD-ROM / DVD-ROM disc tray as well as close it.
You could type it in the console on most (?) of the Linux distributions. Ubuntu is no [exception](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226638/how-to-eject-a-cd-dvd-from-the-command-line).

The icon for ejecting DVD / CD appears once you insert the removable media.
However, I would like to have control on  the opening / closing disc tray even if no CD / DVD is inserted through some widget.

Is there any good frontend for the `eject` tool for the most popular desktop environments? I'm particularly interested in any widget for [Cinnamon](https://www.lifewire.com/install-cinnamon-on-ubuntu-4125605).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make Ejecter working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS or 18.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075481/is-it-possible-to-make-ejecter-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-16-04-lts-or-18-04-l) . Also not that modern file-managers have Eject option (at least Caja and Nautilus have it, maybe Nemo too).

Comment: I think that in possible duplicate question focuses on ejecting already mounted CD/DVD/USB. My concern is that I want to open disc tray **before** inserting CD/DVD (that's what eject command line tool is capable to do).