# Dependency is not satisfiable: udisks

Tags: 18.04, symbolic-link, udisks

I'm having the issue that `udisks` is not found on my system by a deb-Package.
I assume my Ubuntu is newer than the package and it finds `udisks2`.

Probably the problem will be solved easily with a syslink. Did someone run into a similar problem and can tell where I have to set the links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symlink is not a solution because of changed API.
I have ran into similar problem when tried to [use Ejecter on modern Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1075481/66509).

You can get these packages from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and install them manually:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/parted/libparted0debian1_2.3-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/u/udisks/udisks_1.0.5-1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./libparted0debian1_2.3-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./udisks_1.0.5-1_amd64.deb
```

and enjoy:

```
$ udisks
Usage:
  udisks [OPTION…] udisks commandline tool
...
```